# Django 1.9 CharField length modifications are not applied

Tags: python, django, admin, models

I'm using django 1.9 and the admin site for cataloging. 
I changed this in my models.py:

```
localidad = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Localidad')
```

for this:

```
localidad = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Localidad')
```

I saved models.py and made manage.py makemigrations and migrate but changes are not reflected, an error shows up saying the field has 30 character max.
Any help  any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is your app containing the models enabled in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: What exactly is the error that you get ? Is it a database error or a validation error ?

Comment: I realize that the problem was a cache issue, clearing the cache resolved the problem. From manage.py shell:

`from django.core.cache import caches`
and
`cache.clear()`